# Sum and Convert isnt working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am doing a sum in SQL Server and I am trying to do this financial year against last financial year percentage difference, with the code shown below:

```
declare @LastYear table (
[year] nvarchar(40),
total int )

insert @LastYear ([year],[total])
select '2018', count(a.caseno) from activity a
where a.activedate between '2017-04-01' and GETDATE()-365

declare @ThisYear table (
[year] nvarchar(40),
total int)

insert @ThisYear([year],[total])
select '2018', count(a.caseno) from activity a
where a.activedate between '2018-04-01' and GETDATE()

select t.year,sum(convert(decimal(18,2),((t.total/l.total)-1),18))  from 
@ThisYear t
left join @LastYear l on t.year = l.year
group by t.year
```

The answer that I get from it is -1. The answer of the sum should be -0.06. Could you please advide where I am going wrong please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is integer division:

```
t.total / l.total
```

This returns an integer.

The simplest solution is:

```
t.total * 1.0 / l.total
```

Answer (score 1):

on you table you declare `total` as `int`. You should declare it `float`. Try:

```
declare @LastYear table (
[year] nvarchar(40),
total float
)
```

Comment: You have to be careful with `float`s since they are an imprecise number.